# Can I use my Visual Studio Enterprise License in Azure DevOps for multiple AAD accounts?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-active-directory, msdn

When I'm working for external organization that owns Azure DevOps project, they usually create new AAD account for me in their organization.

Is it possible to use my Visual Studio (MSDN) Enterprise license with the account as well? (as well as with my own account, since I work on multiple projects)

**Background:**

In Azure DevOps, there are 5 users for free, additional licenses have to be bought unless the users have MSDN Subscription.

I have MSDN Subscription which shows as a user with Visual Studio Enterprise license in Azure DevOps.

However, when working for customers, I usually have to use different AAD account, which means they have to pay 5$/month even when I have the MSDN

Answer (score 0):

From your description, you want to use an account that’s different from the one that your subscription is assigned to. You may go to http://my.visualstudio.com, click on Subscriptions, and then Add Alternate Account to add new account.

Comment: This will transfer my license, or just add another "alias"? In other words, will I be able to use the benefits with the original account as well?

Comment: I can only add 1 alternative account.  I would like to add more.

Comment: @Cece Dong - MSFT using this same logic can someone use their own VS Ent subscription to get full Basic+Test plan access into someone else DevOps service org? E.g. as a consultant, can I use my VS Ent license to have full access to my client's DevOps service org by using alternative/alias email from my customer (which he created for me)? Or is it possible for my client to enable external access in AAD and directly invite me to their DevOps Service org as Basic+Test plan access for free since I already have my own VS Ent license?